# Can we change background color of a disabled button in lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, button, style, disable

Example:
I understand we can achieve by using slds button base component but any other way directly to achieve through lwc.

```
<lightning-button label="Neutral" title="My Title" disabled class="myClass"></lightning-button>
```

Comment: can you add the content of your CSS class myClass?

Answer (score 2):

In lwc [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/documentation) you can find this statement about css hooks.

> Use SLDS styling hooks to customize the component's styles. For example, specify the background color on the button with brand variant using the --sds-c-button-brand-color-background custom property.

Sample snippet:

```
.myClass {
    --sds-c-button-brand-color-background-disabled: purple;
}
```

In your browser, if you would inspect the button, you could find the right css variable.

[image]

Comment: That would work for normal buttons background color change but he wants to change the color for a disabled button. So your code snippet would change the color if the button is not disabled not in disabled case.

Comment: with the disabled it works the same, i updated my answer to show that

Comment: important to use the right hook - in your example it only works for a brand button (ex. `lightning button variant="brand"`) which OP doesn't seem to be using. Default, if you don't set a variant, is `neutral` so `button-neutral-color-background-disabled`. [See example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/nk5GrCrvNO5Ge9vDnf96).

Comment: Cool, much appreciated but do these styling hooks work in production and is it safe to use them?

Comment: it has been provided by salesforce https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_custom_properties , so it's very much safe to use.